# JsonRequest VS StringRequest in Android Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Android Volley for network calls. Generally I use JSONRequest to receive the json data and then convert them into object using GSON.

```
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       ///Convert response.toString() to POJO using GSON
                    }
                };
```

If I use plain string request and then convert string to objects using GSON, will that be more faster than JSONRequest?

```
new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                  ///Convert response to POJO using GSON
                    }
                };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be more efficient to use `StringRequest` because the raw data returned is in String format, `JSONRequest` convert the String into `JSONObject` which is not necessary for your case.

Actually you may implement your own `GSONRequest`, you can google `GSON volley` for many references.

Here is one example:
[making a GSON request using volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537875/making-a-gson-request-using-volley)

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented, for POJO class, you can create a custom request like the following code because you have to do much work if you use StringRequest.

Here, my POJO class is FileInfo, for example.

```
public class FileRequest extends Request<FileInfo> {
    private final String mRequestBody;
    private final Response.Listener<FileInfo> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;

    private static final String PROTOCOL_CHARSET = "utf-8";
    private static final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE = String.format("application/json; charset=%s", PROTOCOL_CHARSET);

    public FileRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<FileInfo> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mRequestBody = null;
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    public FileRequest(String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<FileInfo> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(requestBody == null ? Method.GET : Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.mRequestBody = requestBody;
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    public FileRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<FileInfo> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mRequestBody = requestBody;
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<FileInfo> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
            fileInfo.Size = Long.valueOf(response.headers.get("Content-Length"));
            fileInfo.Type = response.headers.get("Content-Type");
            fileInfo.Modified = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
            fileInfo.Data = response.data;
            return Response.success(fileInfo, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(FileInfo response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes(PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                mRequestBody, PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thansk. But what benefit does it give?

Comment: @AshwaniK: it will return a generic JsonElement, then you can check if it is a JsonArray or JsonObject. Of course, if you don't want so, you can create a class that extends Request<T> :)

Comment: I think there is some confusion about the question. My question was for json request we can make String request as I use GSON to convert it to POJO.

Comment: IMO, if StringRequest, because of `onResponse(String response)`, you must do much work to parse it and convert it to POJO. Why don't you use a custom request that extends Request<Your POJO> ?