# What is the difference between JSONRequest and StringRequest in volley

Tags: android, json, http, android-volley

I have always read that data comes from server in json format also when we want to send some data we send to the server in json format so data travels in json format then where string request comes from? I dont know if we can post and get data in string format also, and what is the difference and use cases for using string and json requests?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420158/jsonrequest-vs-stringrequest-in-android-volley

Comment: unfortunately It didn't help

Comment: JSONRequest returns the result as a JSONObject. The StringRequest returns the result as a String(the json structure on a string)

Comment: so whole json response is returned in string format?

Comment: If you expect the response to be a JSON object or a JSON Array, save time from implementing serialization and you don't want to explicitly set the content type then `JsonObjectRequest` and `JsonArrayRequest` is the right tool you need. However if it is a different format or you just wanted to use some other serialization/deserialization tool like GSON then the `StringRequest` is the general tool for that. Well so far Volley is lacking of `ByteRequest`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> StringRequest class will be used to fetch any kind of string data. The
>   response can be json, xml, html,text.

```
 // Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
```

> If you are expecting json object in the response, you should use
>   JsonObjectRequest .

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
            URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: what is the benefit using string request, because data returning is still in json format and we have to parse to get string, why specific string request

Comment: by this "StringRequest class will be used to fetch any kind of string data" did you mean if there is data on server that has for example numbers, url etc but string request will only return string in that data?

Comment: @blackHawk Any doubt yet ??

Comment: @blackHawk for your first question read https://stackoverflow.com/a/32420284/3395198

Comment: No, its intersting @IntelliJ

Comment: So its for fetching string data only, from server?

Comment: @blackHawk yes . Data is `RAW` (May be)

Comment: What do you mean by raw?

Comment: @blackHawk `Raw data is data that has not been processed for use`

Answer (score 1):

It's about the return type from the request, `StringRequest` handles a `String` as response like `error = false` and `JSONObjectRequest` handles a `JSONObject` response like `{"error" : false}`, how to know it's `JSONObject` ? with the usage of  brackets (`{`).

Comment: It means response is still in json but in string request only format is changed? its like middleware which converts json into string format?

Comment: nope the response for StringRequest is String, the server returns String, and for the JSONObject the server returns a JSON response

Comment: So that means server can also return data in string format along with json object?

Comment: I just knew that server returns data only in json format

Comment: only one type of data can be returned from server (Json, xml, String ...)

Comment: So its only for fetching string data(on server) in json format?

Comment: it doesn't convert any thing to any format it just get it like it returned

Comment: Only strin data on server?

Comment: that it like that.